# Where should I `dd` mfsBSD to get it to boot correctly?

Tags: boot, freebsd, init, vps, ovh

I'm trying to install freeBSD onto a VPS (OVH provider).

So far, the third method from [this response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410597/installing-freebsd-on-a-vps-using-kvm/410696#410696) has come the closest to getting me where I want to go.  I think OVH has a problem with nested virtualization, because the methods where I boot the installer from QEMU in rescue mode just haven't worked.

The command:

`# https://mfsbsd.vx.sk/files/images/12/amd64/mfsbsd-se-12.1-RELEASE-amd64.img | dd of=/dev/sda`

Actually completes successfully.  When I reboot I even get to see the boot menu!  But then, regardless of whether I boot in multiuser or single user mode I eventually get a message that says `Panic: Going nowhere without my init!`, followed by a vigorous round of reboots.

And now I'm at a total loss.  I assume that init et. al. would be in the image already, so I assume that I must have sent `dd` to the wrong `of=`.

Here's the output of `lsblk` from the rescue mode of my VPS:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0  2.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1    8:1    0  2.5G  0 part /
sdb       8:16   0   20G  0 disk 
├─sdb1    8:17   0 19.9G  0 part /mnt/sdb1
├─sdb14   8:30   0    4M  0 part 
└─sdb15   8:31   0  106M  0 part /mnt/sdb15
```

Should I be writing the image somewhere other than /dev/sda?

**Update:**  I wasn't having any luck getting mfsBSD to boot, and so I went back to trying nested virtualization.  I'm now able to get the KVM started on my VPS, and I've successfully run `bsdinstall`.  However, when I reboot out of rescue mode, I get a grub error.  Still not running FreeBSD yet.

**Further Update:** My VPS is now running FreeBSD quite merrily thanks to a tip from @ClausAndersen.  Here's how I did it:

Reboot in rescue mode from OVH's management panel.  Once logged in (via SSH or KVM, either works), perform the following sequence of commands

1. Unmount your original filesystem with `umount /dev/sdb*`.  Note that the rescue system is mounted from /dev/sda.  Don't touch /dev/sda.
2. Destroy your original filesystem and the partition it lives on with fdisk. `fdisk -u /dev/sdb` followed by a series of `d` until the partition table is empty, then `w`.
3. Install (or confirm that your rescue image has) the package `xz-utils`.  Since my VPS started out life as an Ubuntu server, for me this meant `apt-get install xz-utils`.
4. Get a copy of a ***raw** virtual image* from FreeBSD.org, decompress it, and write it to /dev/sdb.  From the command line in your rescue system, you would type 
   `wget https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/snapshots/VM-IMAGES/12.1-STABLE/amd64/Latest/FreeBSD-12.1-STABLE-amd64.raw.xz | xz -dc | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`

Then reboot and login via KVM in the OVH control panel to configure your FreeBSD server.

Comment: Try `bs=1m` as seen in [this article](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/remote-install/preparation.html) just to be sure. Maybe even `bs=1m conv=sync`.
No dice? Then try [mini-memstick](https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/releases/ISO-IMAGES/12.1/FreeBSD-12.1-RELEASE-amd64-mini-memstick.img). Still? Then capture the output just before the `Panic` and add here.

Comment: Or maybe use the [qcow2](https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/releases/VM-IMAGES/12.1-RELEASE/amd64/Latest/FreeBSD-12.1-RELEASE-amd64.qcow2.xz) image file as shown with [OVHcloud](https://www.ovhcloud.com/en/public-cloud/private-image-catalog/). They list FreeBSD as a [template](https://www.ovhcloud.com/en/public-cloud/public-image-catalog/) as well, Your mention of QEMU made me think you used their cloud offering. But maybe their VPS offering is different?

Comment: @ClausAndersen I've actually abandoned trying to use mfsBSD and taken an alternate approach detailed above.

Comment: If I read the [fdisk](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?fdisk) man page correct then simply use `-i` rather than `-u` for your step number 2 (to simplify). Did not want to update the answer as I have not tested! Is this step even needed? I would assume the partition table would be overwritten by the raw image.

Comment: (and please add your update as an answer and check it as accepted. Then we can upvote :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reboot in rescue mode from OVH's management panel.  Once logged in (via SSH or KVM, either works), perform the following sequence of commands

1. Unmount your original filesystem with `umount /dev/sdb*`.  Note that the rescue system is mounted from /dev/sda.  Don't touch /dev/sda.
2. Destroy your original filesystem and the partition it lives on with fdisk. `fdisk -u /dev/sdb` followed by a series of `d` until the partition table is empty, then `w`.
3. Install (or confirm that your rescue image has) the package `xz-utils`.  Since my VPS started out life as an Ubuntu server, for me this meant `apt-get install xz-utils`.
4. Get a copy of a ***raw** virtual image* from FreeBSD.org, decompress it, and write it to /dev/sdb.  From the command line in your rescue system, you would type 
   `wget https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/snapshots/VM-IMAGES/12.1-STABLE/amd64/Latest/FreeBSD-12.1-STABLE-amd64.raw.xz | xz -dc | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`

Then reboot and login via KVM in the OVH control panel to configure your FreeBSD server.

Note that step 2 may not be necessary; I performed it out of an abundance of caution.  YMMV.